# Store and show multiple date range value SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm currently working on a rental car system and and have a few uncertainties about making a reservation for a car. How to display all the dates when a car reserved.

**Example.**

> Car BMV is reserved from 11.20 2015 to 05.12.2015 also 30.11.205 to
>   10.12.205 and 10.12.2015 to 25.12.2015

If clint want to make new reservation on this date i will create ALERT "This date is reserved for the car".

All that work with single reservation date but i need multiple.

My cuttent database looks like this:

**Bookings:**

```
    id  customer_id  car_id  booking_date  return_date  time_stamp      
------  -----------  ------  ------------  -----------  ----------------
     1            2       5  2015-11-04    2015-11-12   15.06.10 20:10  
     2            3       2  2015-11-02    2015-11-13   15.06.10 20:10  
     3            1      11  2015-11-05    2015-11-16   15.06.10 20:10  
     4            4       8  2015-11-10    2015-12-16   15.06.10 20:10
```

**Car:**

```
   id  car_type_id  branch_id  registration_number  color    date_of_manifacturing  base_price_per_day  
------  -----------  ---------  -------------------  -------  ---------------------  --------------------
     1            1          1  BG-123-431           White     2010-11-15                               30
     2            2          1  BG-A32-212           Metalic  2015-11-04                               30
     3            3          2  PA-332-421           Metalic  2008-05-03                               35
     4            4          1  SM-312-542           Black     2014-06-01                               35
     5            5          1  BG-4393-54           Black     2012-05-03                               50
     6            6          1  NS-423-64            White     2010-10-08                               50
```

Comment: What do you mean by " i need multiple", can you please show what is the expected results for car id 5 for example?

Comment: Like i qoute check if a car is available from Jun/1/2012 5:00 PM to Jun/3/2012 11:00 AM and antoher date to another date etc...  SImilar like hotel reservation system

Comment: Flagged as not constructive. The OP has not asked you to question his business plan.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is a full day reservations, then you can join the two tables to get all the bookings date for a specific car, for example if the BMW car is car_id 5, then this query:

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  b.booking_date,
  b.return_date
FROM Car AS c
INNER JOIN Bookings AS b ON c.id = b.car_id
WHERE c.id = 5;
```

Will give you the list of `booking_date` and `return_date` for that car.

Then, for the formatting par, I don't recommend that you format the dates the way you want in SQL. Better off, In your back end application, you can loop them and display them the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your table structure, you should be able to insert a new row into your `Bookings` table to show a secondary hire period for the same car. This should work when joining to additional tables by `GROUP BY` the car ID.

```
INSERT INTO Bookings
    (Secondary Booking Information)

SELECT
    car_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN @DESIRED_DATE NOT BETWEEN booking_date AND return_date THEN 'True' ELSE NULL END) AS AvailabilityCheck
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY car_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join car table with bookings to know their current booking status and then group it by car id

```
select car.id,car.car_type_id,car.registration_number,
     coalesce(group_concat('Reserverd from ',concat(Bookings.booking_date,' to ',Bookings.return_date)),'Open for bookings') as Booking_status
from car
left join Bookings on car.id=bookings.car_id
group by car.id
```

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8c76/4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT aa.car_type_id, aa.registration_number, bb.car_id, 
CONCAT(DAYOFMONTH(bb.booking_date),'.',MONTH(bb.booking_date),'-',YEAR(bb.booking_date)) AS from_date, 
CONCAT(MONTH(bb.return_date),'.',DAYOFMONTH(bb.return_date),'-',YEAR(bb.return_date)) AS to_date
FROM Car AS aa
INNER JOIN Bookings AS bb
ON aa.id = bb.car_id
WHERE aa.id = 1 AND 'your_date' NOT BETWEEN (bb.booking_date AND bb.return_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all cars once try `group_concat`

```
select t.*,group_concat(concat('from:', t2.booking_date,' to: ',t2.return_date)) reserved_ranges
from cars t
left join bookings t2 on t2.car_id = t.id
group by t.id;
```